# "Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null" - NetBeans (Jar)

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a pending problem of years without being able to solve regarding the execution of a small project (desktop) made in java with NetBeans. Generating the `.jar` file and running it with the `.bat` file gives me the following error message:

```
D:\01 Documentos\00 MI BIBLIOTECA\PROYECTOS PROG\NetbeansProyect\MateDiscreta\dist>java -jar MateDiscreta.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null
        at ClaseFondo.ImagenFondo.<init>(ImagenFondo.java:19)
        at Interfaz.MenuMD.<init>(MenuMD.java:25)
        at Interfaz.MenuMD$9.run(MenuMD.java:215)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

That is to say, the program runs without problems from the IDE. Next, I will show you the general structure of the project:

[image]

As you can see, the file to be executed (main) is the **MenuMD.java**, which is the one that calls the other windows that are inside the **Interfaz** folder through the **Programas** button .

The following code is from **MenuMD.java**:

```
package Interfaz;

import ClaseFondo.ImagenFondo;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class MenuMD extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public MenuMD() {
           
    initComponents();
    
    //Allows to change the window icon
    setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/IconoMD.jpg")).getImage());
    
    //The background class is called, to implement it on the desktop
    escritorioMD.setBorder(new ImagenFondo());
    
    //Allows you to maximize the form
    this.setExtendedState(MenuMD.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    escritorioMD = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
    menuherraMD = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    menuprog = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    menuinfnum = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator3 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    menunumpri = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator4 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    progmcdmcm = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator5 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    menuecudio = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator6 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    menusalir = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    menucred = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    menudatos = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    escritorioMD.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout escritorioMDLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(escritorioMD);
    escritorioMD.setLayout(escritorioMDLayout);
    escritorioMDLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        escritorioMDLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 744, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    escritorioMDLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        escritorioMDLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 221, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    menuprog.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/System.png"))); // NOI18N
    menuprog.setText("Programas");
    menuprog.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menuprogActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(jSeparator1);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator2);

    menuinfnum.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Search.png"))); // NOI18N
    menuinfnum.setText("Info Número");
    menuinfnum.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menuinfnumActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(menuinfnum);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator3);

    menunumpri.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Undo.png"))); // NOI18N
    menunumpri.setText("Generar Num. Primos");
    menunumpri.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menunumpriActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(menunumpri);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator4);

    progmcdmcm.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Tip.png"))); // NOI18N
    progmcdmcm.setText("MCD y MCM");
    progmcdmcm.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            progmcdmcmActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(progmcdmcm);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator5);

    menuecudio.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Stationery.png"))); // NOI18N
    menuecudio.setText("Ecuaciones Diofánticas");
    menuecudio.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menuecudioActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(menuecudio);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator6);

    menusalir.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Close.png"))); // NOI18N
    menusalir.setText("Salir");
    menusalir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menusalirActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(menusalir);

    menuherraMD.add(menuprog);

    menucred.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/user.png"))); // NOI18N
    menucred.setText("Crédito");
    menucred.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menucredActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    menudatos.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Info.png"))); // NOI18N
    menudatos.setText("Datos del Programa");
    menudatos.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menudatosActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menucred.add(menudatos);

    menuherraMD.add(menucred);

    setJMenuBar(menuherraMD);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(escritorioMD)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(escritorioMD)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

private void menucredActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menucredActionPerformed
  
}//GEN-LAST:event_menucredActionPerformed

private void menudatosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menudatosActionPerformed
    Crédito cred = new Crédito();
    escritorioMD.add(cred);
    cred.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menudatosActionPerformed

private void menuprogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menuprogActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_menuprogActionPerformed

private void menusalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menusalirActionPerformed
    System.exit(0);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menusalirActionPerformed

private void menuecudioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menuecudioActionPerformed
    Diofanto dio=new Diofanto();
    escritorioMD.add(dio);
    dio.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menuecudioActionPerformed

private void progmcdmcmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_progmcdmcmActionPerformed
    McdMcm mm = new McdMcm();
    escritorioMD.add(mm);
    mm.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_progmcdmcmActionPerformed

private void menunumpriActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menunumpriActionPerformed
    GenNumPrim gnp = new GenNumPrim();
    escritorioMD.add(gnp);
    gnp.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menunumpriActionPerformed

private void menuinfnumActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menuinfnumActionPerformed
    NatNum inf = new NatNum();
    escritorioMD.add(inf);
    inf.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menuinfnumActionPerformed

public static void main(String args[]) {
           
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       
        public void run() {
            new MenuMD().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JDesktopPane escritorioMD;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator2;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator3;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator4;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator5;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator6;
private javax.swing.JMenu menucred;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menudatos;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menuecudio;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuherraMD;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menuinfnum;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menunumpri;
private javax.swing.JMenu menuprog;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menusalir;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem progmcdmcm;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

And then the code for the `ImagenFondo.java` class:

```
package ClaseFondo;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


public class ImagenFondo implements Border{
public BufferedImage back;

public ImagenFondo(){
    try {
        URL imagePath = new URL(getClass().getResource("../Iconos/FondoUnacFIIS.jpg").toString());
        back = ImageIO.read(imagePath);
    } catch (IOException ex) {            
      }
}

@Override
public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    g.drawImage(back, (x + (width - back.getWidth())/2),(y + (height - back.getHeight())/2), null);
}

@Override
public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
    return new Insets(0,0,0,0);
}

@Override
public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Believe me that I have tried in every possible way with information from the network and with similar cases exposed on this platform, but without success. I don't know how or where to apply the obtaining of the path of the resources that the execution of the **.jar** mentions when executing it.

It would be very helpful, since it would allow me to close and complete this project that I have pending since university.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace? `at ClaseFondo.ImagenFondo.<init>(ImagenFondo.java:19)` - that's where the NPE happens. You haven't showed us that code. Also, the stack trace says `ImagenFondo` is constructed on line 25 of MenuMD.java but I don't see that in the listing you've posted, so your listing is not what you're executing.

Comment: @k314159 , Thanks for answering, actually it was my mistake to delete some lines in the code, that's why they don't match the stack message. That line 25 refers to: `escritorioMD.setBorder(new ImagenFondo());` . I also add the code of ImagenFondo.java as you suggest. Sorry if this is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: I think the problem is that `getClass().getResource("../Iconos/FondoUnacFIIS.jpg")` is returning null. Check the location of your resource in the jar (use a zip file viewer or just `jar --list`). Check the documentation of [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) - it has special rules for the use of "/".